# is there a way to invoke loader method from within the component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using a loader from react-router-dom to fetch data to be used in the component. I also have another function from within the component which updates some information which are initially fetched by the loader function. Is there a way to recall the loader function after the component is rendered so that i can get the latest data after updating.

Comment: Probably not since the route loaders are called prior to the routed component being mounted and rendered. Can you [edit] to provide more detail for the use case and a complete [mcve] for what you are trying to do? You may be able to use the same function for the route loader and action and trigger the action later after the component has mounted.

Comment: You're not working "in react", you're working "in react, in javascript". So: of course you do, just dispatch a custom event in your component, and listen for that event in whatever exists outside your component but manages the loader function. No matter what JS framework or library you're using, JS basics always apply.

Answer (score 1):

Routes run some logic to first check if their fetched data should be revalidated, e.g. rerun the route loaders under several conditions.

See [`shouldRevalidate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/should-revalidate) for details.

There's a list for what triggers automatic revalidation, I've emphasized the one that may be of interest to your use case:

> There are several instances where data is revalidated, keeping your UI
> in sync with your data automatically:
>
> - After an action is called from a .
> - After an action is called from a <fetcher.Form>
> - After an action is called from useSubmit
> - After an action is called from a fetcher.submit
> - When the URL params change for an already rendered route
> - When the URL Search params change
> - ***When navigating to the same URL as the current URL***

You could simply trigger a navigation action to the current route and *that* route's `loader` function will be run again.

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

// "Redirect" to current route path
navigate(".", { replace: true });
```

### Demo

[image: Edit is-there-a-way-to-invoke-loader-method-from-within-the-component-in-react]

Code:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  useNavigate
} from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Mounting useEffect, will trigger data refetch in 5 seconds");

    const timer = setTimeout(navigate, 5000, ".", { replace: true });
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => navigate(".", { replace: true })}>
        Manual reload data
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Home />,
    loader: () => {
      console.log("loading data");
      return null;
    }
  }
]);

export default function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Drew mentioned, the most straightforward way to trigger the loader again is to structure the function that changes the data in such a way that React Router revalidates the data automatically.

> There are several instances where data is revalidated, keeping your UI
> in sync with your data automatically:
>
> - After an action is called from a .
> - After an action is called from a <fetcher.Form>
> - After an action is called from useSubmit
> - After an action is called from a fetcher.submit
> - When an explicit revalidation is triggered via useRevalidator
> - When the URL params change for an already rendered route
> - When the URL Search params change
> - When navigating to the same URL as the current URL

You don't mention how the data is updated, but you might just be able to use React Router's [Form](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/form).

You can also use [useRevalidator](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-revalidator).

> This hook allows you to revalidate the data for any reason. React Router automatically revalidates the data after actions are called, but you may want to revalidate for other reasons like when focus returns to the window.

> Again, React Router already revalidates the data on the page automatically in the vast majority of cases so this should rarely be needed. If you find yourself using this for normal CRUD operations on your data in response to user interactions, you're probably not taking advantage of the other APIs like , useSubmit, or useFetcher that do this automatically.